# Net Maui Property FlexLayout.Shrink does not work as expected

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm trying to use the FlexLayout.Shrink property so that my first element has complete visibility on the line, displaying all the text 'line 1', but the text is not displayed.

I tried using FlexLayout.Shrink='1' so that the element has display priority, but I didn't get the expected result.

Code

```
<ContentPage x:Class="GalleryApp.Views.Layouts.FlexLayoutPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         Title="FlexLayoutPage">
<FlexLayout AlignItems="Start"
            Direction="Row"
            JustifyContent="Start">
    <Label Padding="10"
           BackgroundColor="Brown"
           FlexLayout.Shrink="1"
           Text="Line 1"
           TextColor="White" />
    <Label Padding="10"
           BackgroundColor="RosyBrown"
           FlexLayout.AlignSelf="End"
           Text="Line 2" />
    <Label Padding="10"
           BackgroundColor="SandyBrown"
           Text="Line 3" />
    <Label Padding="10"
           BackgroundColor="LightYellow"
           Text="Line 4" />
    <Label Padding="10"
           BackgroundColor="SandyBrown"
           Text="Line 5" />
    <Label Padding="10"
           BackgroundColor="SandyBrown"
           Text="Line 6" />
    <Label Padding="10"
           BackgroundColor="Blue"
           Text="Line 7" />
</FlexLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: the default value of `Shrink` is "1.0", so all your labels have the same value.  I have no idea if that is the actual problem, but it's the first thing I'd check

Comment: @Jason you're right, I confused the default value with the highest priority, which in this case is 0. I switched it to 0 and it worked.